# ActiveRecord Connection : Custom initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to execute a simple sql line each time a new connection is made (on that same connection)

Why?
Using postgres, "set application_name = 'abc';" will allow me to keep track of the application using the connections when I query my database server for stats.

Haven't seen anything that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar problem recently. I was changing the transaction isolation level after connecting. This example should help you out. It is based on the advice [in the final example on this blog post.](http://www.pluitsolutions.com/2006/10/05/overriding-methods-in-ruby/)

```
# lib/active_record/application_name.rb
module ActiveRecord
  module ApplicationName
    def self.included(base)
      unless base.respond_to? :establish_connection_with_application_name
          base.extend ClassMethods
          base.class_eval do
            class << self
              alias_method_chain :establish_connection, :application_name
            end
          end
      end
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def establish_connection_with_application_name(*args)
        result = establish_connection_without_application_name(*args)
        ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("set application_name = 'abc';")
        result
      end
    end
  end
end

# lib/patches/active_record.rb
require 'active_record/application_name'

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord::ApplicationName
end


# config/initializers/patches.rb
require 'patches/active_record'
```

Comment: This isin't working but the idea was there. Activerecord dosen't pass internaly through establish_connection. It use the pools instead.

Went in and added code around the new_connection method in ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool. Worked fine. If I can find time I'll release some nice code as a gem.

Comment: Ah, cool. In my environment we're calling establish_connection explicitly in a post_fork block in Unicorn, so it worked for me. Thanks for the advice though.